# How to pass event info from aws API Gateway get to Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How do I refer to API Gateway GET query string parameters in a Lambda function ?

When I test I can use my local test event with `"username": "larry"`
When I test with a post I can use the body parameters as the event with `"username": "larry"`
With a get request, I don't have a body.  How could I use query string parameters and then refer to them in the request.  What event or other attribute do I use to get at the query param or what setting or change do I need to make?

#### Method request

[image]

#### Integration request

[image]

#### Query String

[image]

When testing I've referred to event["username", what do I do for an API request passing it as a query string parameter?

Comment: If I understand your question, the event object passed into the Lambda has queryStringParameters and pathParameters. So, event.queryStringParameters.username (if you were using JavaScript, though you didn't indicate a language).

Answer (score 0):

Login and click to API gateway and click on method - GET method

Go to Method Execution -  select URL Query String Parameter and add query String parameter username

Now go to Integration Request tab Choose Body Mapping Template,

```
        "content type application/json"
```

Generate Template like below

```
{
"username":  "$input.params('username')"
}
```

Now write ;ambda which accept  key value in pair .

```
module.exports.get = (event, context, callback) => {
  const { username } = event.pathParameters;
  console.log("username", username); 
}
```

Now  go and deploy your api on apigetway and find url and hit in browser example

```
          https://xxx.yyy-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/prod/username?vaquarkhan
```

Hope it will help

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/apigateway/latest/developerguide/welcome.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-set-up-lambda-proxy-integration-on-proxy-resource